# Totally linearization $(x^2•y)•y - ((x•y)•y)•x = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a homework I have doing linearization of this identity $(x^2•y)•y - ((x•y)•y)•x = 0$ in  an arbitrary algebra.
I stuck with the end.
The big dot is just an arbitrary product.
 I have a problem in my answer replaced $x$ by $x+z$. 
I have,
 $$((xz)y)y - ((zy)y)x + ((zx)y)y - ((xy)y)z =0$$ 
I don't know to do with. 
Is this the final form of it?

Comment: Linearizing that identity has nothing to do with whether it is or not related to the Moufang identity.

Comment: In any case, are you asking what the Moufang identities are? There is a Wikipedia page on the subject (Moufang loops), if I recall correctly. Does it not answer your question?

Comment: The big dot is just an arbitrary product.  I have a problem in my answer replaced $x$ by $x+z$ I have $((xz)y)y - ((zy)y)x + ((zx)y)y - ((xy)y)z =0$ I don't know to do with.

Comment: Notice the identity is not linear in $y$ also. In any case, you have to tell us what your problem **is**, not only that you have a problem.ç